# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I've encountered this error below when trying to follow along on a Udemy JS project.  3 of my full time dev friends can't figure it out and I've read 10 - 15 StackOverflow articles about this error as well as its variations and nothing seemed to apply.

Here's the common errror:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null
    at Object.displayBudget (app.js:177)
    at updateBudget (app.js:219)
    at ctrlAddItem (app.js:236)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.js:205)
```

It seems pretty straight forward but the common solutions of placing the script at the bottom of the HTML right before the closing body tag and not having a matching element by the name queried do not apply.  I've triple checked both things and even added the JQuery .ready function at someone's suggestion to ensure the page was loading.

I've set break points in the console for all line referenced above and stepped through the code and directly before the failure it looks like my variable is defined and is not NULL.  See picture attached or below.

[Code Step Through](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qH8W.png)

That 'budget__value' totally exists in the html.

```
<body>

        <div class="top">
            <div class="budget">
                <div class="budget__title">
                    Available Budget in <span class="budget__title--month">%Month%</span>:
                </div>

                <div class="budget__value">+ 2,345.64</div>
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Laflamme02/3uy9vp89/) of my code.  I've also pushed it up to Github (/Laflamme02/BudgetApp) if you want to see what I'm getting myself into here.

I've been struggling with this for at least 2 weeks so whoever helps me solve this will be my favorite person ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the dot in front of the class name in your `DOMString.budgetLabel`. It should read:

```
document.querySelector('.budget__value').textContent = obj.budget
```

From your JSFiddle, you can see that you forgot to put the dot in front of several other strings as well: `incomeLabel`, `expensesLabel`, and `percentageLabel`. All four are simple fixes.

```
var DOMstrings = {
    inputType:          '.add__type',
    inputDescription:   '.add__description',
    inputValue:         '.add__value',
    inputBtn:           '.add__btn',
    incomeContainer:    '.income__list',
    expensesContainer:  '.expenses__list',
    budgetLabel:        'budget__value',
    incomeLabel:        'budget__income--value',
    expensesLabel:      'budget__expenses--value',
    percentageLabel:    'budget__expenses--percentage'
};
```

Comment: This is my favorite thing to have ever felt stupid about.  @gyre, you are my new favorite person.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help! Also, I just checked your JSFiddle and there are three more typos like that one. See my edited post above.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myHeading=document.querySelector('h1');
myHeading.textContent='Hello World';
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>

        </title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1></h1>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```